# execute docker command from keepalived notify script

Tags: bash, permissions, docker

I'm struggling with this one for a few days now and I appreciate any help.
Basically, I want to use keepalived between two servers running docker-compose, so when one is changed to be master I want to do docker-compose up and on the backup server docker-compose down.
While trying to set it up I was able to execute the notify script with the correct user (I echoed it before the docker command) but when trying to do  `docker run --name hello hello-world` I got permission denied.

another question is how can I see the keepalived logs besides service status.

this is the keepalived conf

```
global_defs {
   notification_email_from lb1@mydomain.com
   smtp_server localhost
   smtp_connect_timeout 30
   script_user sky
   enable_script_security
}

vrrp_instance VI_1 {
    state MASTER
    interface enp0s9
    virtual_router_id 101
    priority 101
    advert_int 1
    authentication {
        auth_type PASS
        auth_pass 1111
    }
    virtual_ipaddress {
        10.1.10.30
    }
    notify "/home/sky/keepchange.sh"
}
```

this is the keepchange.sh script

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 >> /home/sky/keepalived.txt
echo $(whoami) >> /home/sky/keepalived.txt
/bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/docker run --name hello -d hello-world' &>> /home/sky/keepalived.txt
```

and this is the output inside keepalived.txt

```
INSTANCE VI_1 FAULT 101
sky
docker: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.40/containers/create?name=hello: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied.
See 'docker run --help'.
INSTANCE VI_1 BACKUP 101
sky
docker: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.40/containers/create?name=hello: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied.
See 'docker run --help'.
INSTANCE VI_1 MASTER 101
sky
docker: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.40/containers/create?name=hello: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

any help and suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: Did you check if the script-user "sky" is in the docker group?